# Set Enumerability Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Define a word as a finite string of letters of an infinite enumerable alphabet a1, a2, a3...

Show that

```
The set of all two-letter words is enumerable

For any positive whole number n, the set of all n letter works is enumerable

The set of all words is enumerable
```

I'm fairly certain that I have to try and map these sets to the positive integers in order to prove their enumerability, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Mathnasium Stack Exchange Tim.

I'm going to solve the first case: all other versions are extensions of this case. In particular, I'm going to show a more limited result: that there is an injection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. We can imagine the first coordinate to be the first letter of our word, the second coordinate to be the second letter, and the target to be the word's position on our list.

So, define $f(n, m)$ by $f(n, m) = 2^n3^m$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $2^n3^m = 2^{n'}3^{m'}$ if and only if $n = n'$ and $m = m'$. That is, $f$ is injective, proving that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is enumerable.

To prove the further cases, notice that all we really used about $\mathbb{N}$ is that $2$ and $3$ are the first two prime numbers. If I wanted to prove something about a string of three numbers, what bases would I use?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Assuming you mean **finite** strings then try to convert numbers in base $n.$ Are not those in bijection with the strings? For example: $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ correspond to $000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111.$ This idea should be enough to deal with the first two. The third has a problem and is that you can have as many digits as you want. So what if you count how many digits you have and pass it to that base. Probably knowing that $\mathbb{N}^2$ is countable should help.